# Codeigniter cron job issue

Tags: linux, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface, php

I have a cron job which needs running on my site. I have set up the model and controller, then set the following cron job to run every hour:

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/directory/index.php cron resetViews;
```

I have the URI_PROTOCOL index of $config in my config.php file is set to AUTO and there are no spelling errors.

When I run the command, I get the4 html of my home page, which is also my default controller. Any ideas?

**Edit**

I have changed the command to:

```
cd /path/to/directory; /usr/bin/php index.php cron resetViews;
```

and now I get the following error on top of a printout of my home page:

> PHP:  Error parsing /home/crowston/public_html/2012/php.ini on line 1

Here is my entire php.ini file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

I have also tried with a blank php.ini fie to no avail.

The php.ini file has caused no errors throughout the entire construction of the site :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
wget http://localhost/index.php/cron/resetViews
```

Basically, since you have the capability to use wget that will definitely call the controller method, why use cli?

EDIT:

referring to [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html), perhaps you should do a `cd` command to the directory and then call index.php. Worth a try because if ci was trying to load controller from path relative to the cron's pwd, then it might throw a 404. right?

Comment: Because I can use $this->input->is_cli_request() to stop the cron being run by a web user. Will this command be blocked? I thought it would

Comment: You can use a key parameter to the cron job method and check if the it is matching before processing the job else return. You can even make the key configurable by placing it in the config file. Same technique I am using in the code for email queue agent in thephpcode.com's code generator.

Comment: @Nish What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean to stop unwanted execution of cron functions by url calling, you can use a parameter in your cron method. Then check for specific value of the parameter before executing the cron action. function abc($param){ if($param!='something') return; ...}

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me :

wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.mani.com/project-name/index.php/tools/sendPushNotification

(-O /dev/null -q) Command is used to remove log file